# Pulling packages from a CentOS VM in Virtual Box down to a host OS

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I am looking to get a specific list of packages uploaded to an offline CentOS VM. To do this, I am spinning up a networked CentOS VM in Virtual Box to download the correct packages. Is there an easy way to transfer the packages to the OS that is hosting the networked CentOS VM so that I can put them on some removable media to later upload to the offline CentOS VM? Is my best bet to use FTP or SCP?

For some justification: I am doing things this way, rather than just going to something like rpmfind.com and downloading the packages so I can account for dependencies in an efficient manner.

In case the information is needed, the host OS is running macOS 10.14.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the host altogether. VirtualBox lets you connect host's USB devices to guest. If your goal is to transfer files to a removable media like a USB disk, just connect it to the VM. You can do this under *Devices → USB* in VirtualBox machine's window.

Comment: This worked after some troubleshooting. I had the USB device plugged in when I fired up the VM and it had trouble recognizing the USB device. By firing up the VM and then plugging in the USB I was able to mount it and use it just fine. One other small issue I had was the file system format. Apparently CentOS7 doesn't like journal-ed file systems, so I had to reformat from HFSPlus to exFAT and download a few additional packages to support my use of exFAT.

Comment: @peachykeen It's not strictly a journaling problem. ext4 (Linux's standard FS nowadays) and its predecessor are journaled too. But HFS+ is basically non-existent outside of Apple's ecosystem, so that's why you had problems with it. exFAT is nice but still usually not supported out of the box. If you want to have highest compatibility, use NTFS or embrace limitations of FAT32.